# How to get bitcoins for testin in my block chain wallet?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

I'm creating a website and i'm using the block chain web socket but i need test bitcoins to do lots of tests to see if the site works correctly, I tried using testnet not sure how to get the bitcoins into my wallet or if there is anyway to do this, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. You should post things like this on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

There is some websites called "faucets" where you just need to type your bitcoin address and they generate and send you coins to test.

For example:
   https://testnet.coinfaucet.eu/en/